# Check if a variable has a value or null?

Tags: linux, shell

Below if condition is not working properly. Please advise.
I have java process id , but below working "No process alive". Why if [ -z $PIDS ] not working ?

```
PIDS= pgrep -f java

if [ -z "$PIDS" ]
then
echo "No process alive...."
exit 1
else
echo "An instace is running in background."
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `PIDS` to contain the output of running that command, you need to tell the shell that:

```
PIDS="$(pgrep -f java)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first line should read

```
PIDS="$(pgrep -f java)"
```